# Remote execution from SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, remote-access, psexec

I have server A with SSIS running and an executable file in server B. I need to run this executable file from SSIS.

I tried with [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) and managed to run the executable from server A. But, I need to execute this from SSIS and have no idea how to do it from SSIS or incorporate PsExec with SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run this executable using the [Execute Process Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-process-task?view=sql-server-ver15).

[image]

Just copy the `PsExec` command you used into the `Executable` property in the Execute Process Task editor. Or you can put `PsExec` into the `Executable` property and the rest of the command into the `Arguments` property.

[image]

You can learn more about this control in the following article:

- [SSIS Execute Process Task Tutorial with Examples](https://blog.devart.com/execute-process-task-in-ssis.html)
- [The Basics of the Execute Process Task](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/06/11/sql-server-the-basics-of-the-execute-process-task-notes-from-the-field-084/)